# Concat node_modules for Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp, systemjs, gulp-concat

I have an Angular 2 app in which I of cause have a lot of node_modules.
I need to concatenate these, but I simple dont know how. I have tried to do it in gulp: 
[image]

But when I run it I get the following:

[image]

Something tells me that I have some es6 modules which gives me trouble, but I simply don't know.

This is my SystemJS file.

```
(function (global) {

// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
    'app': 'app',
    'rxjs': 'lib/rxjs',
    '@angular': 'lib/@angular',
    "ng2-nvd3": "lib/ng2-nvd3/build/lib/ng2-nvd3.js",
    "angular2-datatable/datatable": "lib/angular2-datatable/datatable.js",
    'lodash': 'https://npmcdn.com/lodash@4.6.1/lodash.js'
};

// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
    'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'lib': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
};

var packageNames = [
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    '@angular/router-deprecated',
    '@angular/testing',
    '@angular/upgrade',
    '@angular/forms'
];

// add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
packageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});

var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
};

// filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
if (global.filterSystemConfig) {
    global.filterSystemConfig(config);
}

System.config(config);

})(this);
```

Is there someone who can tell me what to do. I am without a clue.